# Does C always have to use pointers to handle addresses?

Tags: c, pointers, memory-address

As I understand it, all of the cases where C has to handle an address involve the use of a pointer. For example, the & operand creates a pointer to the program, instead of just giving the bare address as data (i.e it never gives the address without using a pointer first):

```
scanf("%d", &foo)
```

Or when using the & operand

```
int i; //a variable
int *p; //a variable that store adress
p = &i; //The & operator returns a pointer to its operand, and equals p to that pointer.
```

My question is: Is there a reason why C programs always have to use a pointer to manage addresses? Is there a case where C can handle a bare address (the numerical value of the address) on its own or with another method? Or is that completely impossible? (Being because of system architecture, memory allocation changing during and in each runtime, etc). And finally, would that be useful being that addresses change because of memory management? If that was the case, it would be a reason why pointers are always needed.

I'm trying to figure out if the use pointers is a must in C standardized languages. Not because I want to use something else, but because I want to know for sure that the only way to use addresses is with pointers, and just forget about everything else.

Edit: Since part of the question was answered in the comments of  Eric Postpischil,  Michał Marszałek, user3386109, Mike Holt and Gecko; I'll group those bits here: Yes, using bare adresses bear little to no use because of different factors (Pointers allow a number of operations, adresses may change each time the program is run, etc). As Michał Marszałek pointed out (No pun intended) scanf() uses a pointer because C can only work with copies, so a pointer is needed to change the variable used. i.e

```
int foo;
scanf("%d", foo) //Does nothing, since value can't be changed
scanf("%d", &foo) //Now foo can be changed, since we use it's address.
```

Finally, as Gecko mentioned, pointers are there to represent indirection, so that the compiler can make the difference between data and address.

John Bode covers most of those topics in it's answer, so I'll mark that one.

Comment: A pointer is C's way of representing an address, so, yes, you always have to use pointers to handle addresses.

Comment: I don't think there is such a thing as 'the bare address'.  For instance, in your example, `foo` is (presumably) an integer value, not "the bare address" of an integer value.  The `&` operator yields the address of that integer as a pointer.  (There is such a thing as a `void *` in C, but that's just a pointer with the type-information stripped out -- avoid using that when possible, it's easy to use it wrong, because the compiler won't be able to help you detect mistakes)

Comment: A address is a numerical value, you can use unsigned int to hold an address as long as the address fits in the value. Point are there to represent indirection, so that the compiler can make the difference between data and address

Comment: Yes @JeremyFriesner, foo was a placeholder for a variable of any type (char, int or array. Although I think arrays are handled differently). My question was that for that variable, the & operator never gives just the address, but a pointer to it, and why that happens.

Comment: I'm not seeing the distinction you're making -- what would "just the address" look like?  How is "just the address" different from a pointer?

Comment: @Chabon A pointer is just a variable like any other. It's contents *are* the "bare address". You can examine a pointer variable in a debugger and it will show the memory address. The distinction between pointer and "bare address" you keep mentioning doesn't exist. A pointer is just a numerical address value with some built-in semantics.

Comment: Btw `printf("%p\n", &foo);` is also a good way to see the pointer's current value (i.e. the address of the object the pointer is pointing to)

Comment: @geckos but being that an addresses always changes in runtime because of memory managment, isn't it useless to do that? If that was the case, then it would be a reason why pointers are always needed.

Comment: @MikeHolt then why does & give a pointer and not the content itself? Why is there a need to make another variable? (Edit: Sorry if the questions look aggressive,  I'm just bad at english)

Comment: @Chabon, Why *wouldn't* `&` give you a pointer? If it just returned an `unsigned int` containing the memory address, the only difference would be the underlying *type* of the variable. But they still hold the same exact value. Just like `int x = 10;` vs `char y = 10;`. One is an `int` and the other is a `char`, but they both just contain the value `10`. You're getting hung up on this notion that a pointer is some strange animal, when all it really is is the same address, just with some extra semantics attached, such as being able to dereference with `*`.

Comment: @MikeHolt I was just asking if there was an underlying reason on the use of a pointer, an extra variable in code, instead of an unsigned int with the address. Are those extra semantics the pointer allows the reason why an extra variable (the pointer) is used?

Comment: @Chabon Objects' addresses don't change due to "memory management".  C doesn't have a garbage collector or similar.  Objects don't move around in memory like in some languages.  A pointer is just an integer that holds the address of some other object.  Its value doesn't change unless you change it.  They allow some different language-level operations (i.e. subscripting, different addition semantics), but at the assembly level there's no difference (on most modern architectures).

Comment: In user code on a desktop system, hardcoded addresses (bare address) are not useful because the program cannot access anything that would be at a fixed address. In embedded systems, there *are* memory addresses (used for memory mapped I/O) that are fixed. So on an embedded system, there are places where hardcoded addresses are used. Typically, those addresses are hidden in #defines so that the numbers don't clutter the code.

Comment: @MilesBudnek sorry, I didn't mean memory management like that, but in the sense that addresses change every time the program runs. Since it will run on a different block of memory each time, using an int static address could be impractical, and a reason to use pointers instead. That is what I meant.

Comment: @user3386109 Yes, this is exactly what I meant by fixed and not fixed adresses and memory management (And what I tried to ask to Miles). Thank you.

Comment: There's nothing stopping you from going `int i; *(&i) = 5;` and using the "bare address" without a pointer variable but it should be pretty clear that the above is quite pointless (but not pointer-less ;) ). Internally the address is still a pointer and treated as such.

Comment: That closes the question. Bare adresses are pointless. Thank you Michael.

Comment: @MikeHolt no a pointer is **not** an `unsigned int`.  The only integer types it can be converted into are `intptr_t` and `uintptr_t`. \@Chabon `instead of an unsigned int with the address` how can you use an integer to point to a variable when you have absolutely no idea where a variable is located? The `&` operator allows you to take the address of a variable. Besides, using magic number is a bad practice, regardless of whatever variable and type you want

Comment: @phuclv WTH? At **no** point did I say a pointer is an unsigned int. I said a pointer is just a numeric value (which it is), with some built-in semantics and syntax. And I said that (on some architectures, assuming a pointer would actually fit in an unsigned int), that you could easily convert a pointer to an unsigned int (or whatever size integer you need to fit a pointer value, depending on your architecture). Not that you would want to, of course. I only mentioned that because OP seemed to think a pointer was some strange object with all sorts of automatic stuff going on in the background.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A pointer *is* an address (or, more properly, it’s an abstraction of an address).  Pointers are how we deal with address values in C.

Outside of a few domains, a “bare address” value simply isn’t useful on its own.  We’re less interested in the address than the object at that address.  C *requires* us to use pointers in two situations:

- When we want a function to write to a parameter
- When we need to track dynamically allocated memory

In these cases, we don’t really care what the address value actually is; we just need it to access the object we’re interested in.

Yes, in the embedded world specific address values are meaningful.  But you still use pointers to access those locations.  Like I said above, a pointer *is* an address for our purposes.

Answer (score 1):

```
int i; //a variable
int *p; //a variable that store adres
i = 10; //now i is set to 10
p = &i; //now p is set to i address
*p = 20; //we set to 20 the given address
int tab[10]; // a table
p = tab; //set address
p++; //operate on address and move it to next element tab[1]
```

We can operate on address by pointers move forward or backwards. We can set and read from given address.

In C if we want get return values from functions we must use pointers. Or use return value from functions, but that way we can only get one value.

In C we don't have references therefore we must use pointers.

```
void fun(int j){
j = 10;
}
void fun2(int *j){
*j = 10;
}
int i;
i = 5; // now I is set to 5
fun(i);
//printf i will print 5
fun2(&i);
//printf I will print 10
```

Comment: That seems like a good reason. Sorry if I keep repeating the question, but does that mean that the only (And I mean **only**) way of using addresses in a practical manner is by creating a pointer variable, and nothing else?

Comment: Pointer in itself is variable. In C when we call functions the compiler is making copy of variables we passed to functions. Therefore we can't get any return value by that method. But if we pass address to it it can change the variable that the address is set. I will edit my answer to better answer it.

Comment: I know that is a reason of the use of pointers in parameters passage. But, does that mean that the & operator is a function and that is why a pointer var is used instead of an unsigned int?

Comment: No & is not a function. & is a operator that works on variables and returns the address or the variable. (I don't understand the question)

Answer (score 1):

C allows you to convert pointers to integers. The `<stdint.h>` header provides a `uintptr_t` type with the property that any pointer to `void` can be converted to `uintptr_t` and back, and the result will compare equal to the original pointer.

Per C 2018 6.3.2.3 6, the result of converting a pointer to an integer is implementation-defined. Non-normative note 69 says “The mapping functions for converting a pointer to an integer or an integer to a pointer are intended to be consistent with the addressing structure of the execution environment.”

Thus, on a machine where addresses are a simple numbering scheme, converting a pointer to a `uintptr_t` **ought** to give you the natural machine address, even though the standard does not require it. There are, however, environments where addresses are more complicated, and the result of converting a pointer to an integer may not be straightforward.

Comment: @Chabon: That depends on the task you want to use it for. If you want to store or retrieve the contents of some object in C, you must use a pointer. However, if you want to align addresses for special purposes (e.g., implementing fast SIMD code), you may need to work with addresses as integers, then convert them back.